# How to create and arrange my html form?

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I want to create a form in html like this image. But i can't arrange it like in this picture.
[image]

Here is my code so far.

```
 <form>
 <div>
 <br></br>
 <p><font size="2">Prepared and Submitted by: _________________           Reviewed & Validated by: __________________  Noted: ___________________  
</p>
<p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SCHOOL HEAD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; DIVISION    REPRESENTATIVE  SCHOOLS DIVISION SUPERINTENDENT </pr>
</font>

<p><strong><font size="3">Guidelines:</strong> </font> </pr>

 <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1">1. After receiving and validating the Report for Promotion submitted by the class adviser, the School Head shall compute the grade level total and school total.</font></pr>
 <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1">2. This report together with the copy of Report for Promotion submitted by the class adviser shall be forwarded to the Division Office by the end of the school year.</font>  </pr>
 <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1">3. The Report on Promotion per grade level is reflected in the End of School Year Report of GESP/GSSP.</font></pr>
 <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1">4. Protocols of validation & submission is under the discretion of the Schools Division Superintendent.</font></pr>

</div>
</form>
```

I'm new in html. Help me please....

Answer (score 0):

As a new user of html, you should have a look at css properties.

It will help you for element positionning.

For instance, use margin and padding properties :

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_margin_sides

Try also to split your view with div anchor.
You could put the 4 points in one div and use css properties to put the div on the right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could use Bootstrap. You can get it here: getbootstrap.com

The following could would then work:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Prepared and Submitted by:</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
    <p class="help-block">SCHOOL HEAD</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Reviewed &amp; Validated by:</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
    <p class="help-block">DIVISION    REPRESENTATIVE</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Noted: </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Guidelines: </label>
  <ol class="list-unstyled"> 
       <li>After receiving and validating the Report for Promotion submitted by the class adviser, the School Head shall compute the grade level total and school total.</li>
       <li>This report together with the copy of Report for Promotion submitted by the class adviser shall be forwarded to the Division Office by the end of the school year.</li>
       <li>The Report on Promotion per grade level is reflected in the End of School Year Report of GESP/GSSP.</li>
       <li>Protocols of validation & submission is under the discretion of the Schools Division Superintendent.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you should put more emphasis on the fact that this uses Bootstrap, as for people who don't know this it might not be completely obvious.

Comment: yeah. Thats true @Peter :)